# How to start out Watchface development with missing template on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, wear-os

I freshly installed Android Studio and wanted to follow these docs: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/service#create-project in there it talks about a template, but it doesnt seem to exist for me.
Did I not install something?
Did they just remove it? But then how do I start out?

Tryed: Creating "New Project" then going on WearOS.
Expecting: An option to select a Watch Face template

Comment: There is a bug raised to update the documentation and/or Android Studio: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295282549. Have you tried following the steps of the documentation with the other templates? You might have to add the watch faces [dependencies](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/blob/2bd2418b4e8101c948ddaba9d88f6d2cadec261c/WatchFaceKotlin/gradle/libs.versions.toml#L29-L36) manually after that. You could also use [WatchFaceKotlin](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/main/WatchFaceKotlin) project as a template.

Comment: Any idea - apart from using an old Android-Studio-Version - how to get a clean Java-Template?